# ASP.NET MVC Pagination using Take and Skip

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagination

EDIT: This question has been made redundant by this question as much of the code changed from using a repository to using just the controller: [(Homework) MVC Pagination Help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662611/mvc-pagination-help)

Comment: Cameron - i've created a smaple for you identical to your object structure. i'll pop the url on my answer

Comment: Are you asking people to write this for you?

Comment: No just want to see some examples similar to what I have been doing, all the examples posted went in totally different directions to my current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cameron,

I can point you to an example that I created a wee while back for someone here on SO (using an IPagedList interface). it works as a htmlhelper but may be more featured than you're after. it follows the pattern here on SO for paging, i.e.:

[image]

Comment: I was unable to open your file I'm afraid as I have a different version I think. However I'm looking for something very simple. Just basically showing 4 results per page and showing a simple pagination to jump between these pages.

Comment: no worries - that example was saved as vs2008 version for maximum compatability. strange!!

Comment: Looked at some of the code in Notepad. It's defo way more complicated than what I'm looking for. I want it to be very simple. Would you be able to help me implement a very simple pagination like explained in my question? Thanks.

Comment: cameron, the main pointers that i'd give would be that your index method will have to implemnt some sort of mechanism for retriveing the page number and page size that your interested in. this would boil down to either a post or a request passing those in. also, your linq qery will have to perform a ArticleQuery.Take(pageSize).Skip(pageIndex) sort of manouvre.

Comment: @Jim could you show an example of what I would need to put in my controller and view. As I'm new to MVC and looking to get it working and then play around with it and hopefully learn more from it as I mess with the code. Thanks again.

Comment: cameron, heading off now but will update with a few lines in the answer tmro to show how you might do this simply (unless someone adds an answer in the interim). g'night for now

Comment: cameron, i've created anew sample for you that is far simpler and uses your structure plus simple paging along with a partialview.. enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest the following article: [Displaying a Paged Grid of Data in ASP.NET MVC](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020001747/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/010511-1.aspx). It walks through displaying a paged grid of data and building a paging interface in detail.

Comment: @Cameron: Another option would be to use the Grid and Pager helpers in the MvcContrib project - http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/

Comment: @Cameron: I suggest you read the article I provide. I think it's pretty straightforward and will make much sense as you read through it. Learning the *concepts* is more important than learning how to solve a specific problem. :-)

Comment: @Cameron: Start with the first article in the series and work through it. It shows how to use Linq-to-Sql (very similar to EF) and walks through first displaying data, then sorting, then paging. An upcoming article will show how to filter, too.

Comment: I posit that if you read through the article and learn the concepts then you will be able to apply them to your particular problem. I hold that if you spend an hour working through those three articles it will be a very rewarding hour spent.

Comment: Yeah I read the articles but they seem out of scope for what I wanted to achieve. I found this to be more inline: http://nerddiners.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

you could also try this approach (a button that shows more results, instead of going to the next page)

http://demo.aspnetawesome.com/AjaxListDemo

or a simple pager
http://demo.aspnetawesome.com/PagerDemo