# (Homework) MVC Pagination Help

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagination

I'm attempting to put together a very simple application using ASP.NET MVC that shows news articles and paginates them. I'm sort of half-way there but need some help sorting out the pagination and getting it to work with the search query.

Here is my HomeController:

```
public ActionResult Index(String query, int? page)
{
        // limit the number of articles per page
        const int pageSize = 4;
        // build the query
        var ArticleQuery = from a in _db.ArticleSet select a;
        // check if their is a query
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
        {
            ArticleQuery = ArticleQuery.Where(a => a.headline.Contains(query));
        }
        // orders the articles
        var OrderedArticles = ArticleQuery.OrderByDescending(a => a.posted);
        // takes the ordered articles and paginates them
        //var paginatedArticles = new PaginatedList(OrderedArticles.Skip((page ?? 0) * pageSize).Take(pageSize), page ?? 0, pageSize);
        var paginatedArticles = new PaginatedList<Article>(OrderedArticles, page ?? 0, pageSize);
        // return the paginated articles to the view
        return View(paginatedArticles);
}
```

The idea is that the Controller shows 4 items per page will order them by date. Here is the View I have for the Index method:

```
<ul id="pagination">
    <% if (Model.PreviousPage) { %>
        <li><%= Html.ActionLink("<< First Page", "Index")%></li>
        <li><%= Html.ActionLink("<< Previous Page", "Index", new { page=(Model.PageIndex-1) }) %></li>
    <% } %>
    <% if (Model.NextPage) { %>
        <li><%= Html.ActionLink("Next Page >>", "Index", new { page = (Model.PageIndex + 1) })%></li>
        <li><%= Html.ActionLink("Last Page >>", "Index", new { page = (Model.TotalPages - 1) })%></li>
    <% } %>    
</ul>
```

The idea is that these two pagination links will only show if the conditions are true.

Finally here is the PaginatedList class for the pager:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace NewsApp.Models
{
    public class PaginatedList<T> : List<T>
    {
        public int PageIndex { get; private set; }
        public int PageSize { get; private set; }
        public int TotalCount { get; private set; }
        public int TotalPages { get; private set; }

        public PaginatedList(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
        {
            PageIndex = pageIndex;
            PageSize = pageSize;
            TotalCount = source.Count();
            TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(TotalCount / (double)PageSize);

            this.AddRange(source.Skip(PageIndex * PageSize).Take(PageSize));
        }
        public bool HasPreviousPage
        {
            get
            {
                return (PageIndex > 0);
            }
        }
        public bool HasNextPage
        {
            get
            {
                return (PageIndex + 1 < TotalPages);
            }
        }
    }
```

**NOTE: I' don't want to use any 3rd party components like MVCContrib etc as this is for a University assignment so would defeat the purpose.**

The pagination works fine now but when I do a search and have e.g. /?query=test I want to be able to page the results, at the moment they get lost :/

Thanks.

Comment: just answered something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659978/asp-net-mvc-pagination-using-take-and-skip/4662573#4662573

Comment: Googled CHT2520 because I was suspicious.  Only results look like school class schedules.  Looks like somebody has homework due tomorrow?

Comment: I'm not sure what that has to do with anything? Plus it's not due for tomorrow! :) By the way I found the solution, please see updated answer, but I have a second problem in that the query gets lost when I navigate pages. Any ideas how to fix this. Thanks.

Comment: Also added (Homework) tag to title :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't cite what you're actual error is, but I think I see what's wrong:

These two lines will return your an IEnumerable containing your results.

```
var paginatedArticles = OrderedArticles.Skip((page ?? 0) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();

return View(paginatedArticles);
```

However, based on your view and the helper class you posted, you're view is expecting `PaginatedList` object as its Model.

If that's the case, I'd do the following (**updated**):

```
var paginatedArticles = new PaginatedList( OrderedArticles, page ?? 0, pageSize );

return View(paginatedArticles);
```

And then your view should have the proper model being returned to it.

That said: I don't know why you aren't using a repository layer, but unless your app is only a single page it is almost always a good idea to have one in place.

**Update** --here's what I think the full controller logic should be:

```
public ActionResult Index(String query, int? page)
{
    const int pageSize = 4;

    var ArticleQuery = from m in _db.ArticleSet select m;

    // Searching
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
    {
        ArticleQuery = ArticleQuery.Where(m => m.headline.Contains(query));
    }

    var OrderedArticles = ArticleQuery.OrderByDescending(m => m.posted);

    var paginatedArticles = new PaginatedList( OrderedArticles, page ?? 0, pageSize );
    // this will now be of type paginatedList. this class handles all of the paging for you, so no need to do that ahead of time

    return View(paginatedArticles);
}
```

In this case, PaginatedList is NOT a helper --its a full on class that needs to be created and passed to your model. A helper in the strict definition of the word is done much differently and probably wouldn't work in your case here.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. I'm not using a repos. What I need is to change the Helper class to work with my controller as it was written originally for a repository which I'm not using in this case. Could you help me rewrite it to work. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also if I don't bring the OrderedArticles across, then they will no longer be ordered will they?

Comment: Nothing I posted there has need of any repository, it can all go directly in your controller. In this case, you're passing `OrderedArticles` into the constructor of your `PaginatedList` class. It seems to me this is the class you should be returning to your view so you can access the next/previous page options and such. I see one thing I missed, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Moved the PaginatedList into my Models folder which fixes the problems with the View. But I get this error in my controller: Error 5 Using the generic type 'CHT2520_u0558234_1a.Models.PaginatedList<T>' requires '1' type arguments C:\Users\cameron\Desktop\NON-REPOS\CHT2520-u0558234-1a\Controllers\HomeController.cs 35 41 CHT2520-u0558234-1a

Comment: Try `var paginatedArticles = new PaginatedList<ArticleSet>(OrderedArticles, page ?? 0, pageSize );`

Comment: Says it can't find <ArticleSet>

Comment: I'm having a really hard time helping at this point.. it seems like a lot of things may be wrong with the application and you're trying to do too much in the first go-around. The type, I think, should be whatever gets returned from this: `var ArticleQuery = from m in _db.ArticleSet select m;` I would recommend pairing everything and slowly add in each piece on-by-one at this point

Comment: Just tried this and it worked :) `var paginatedArticles = new PaginatedList<Article>(OrderedArticles, page ?? 0, pageSize);`

Comment: Problem I am having though is if I do a search and have say 8 results, the pagination appears but won't keep the query ie paginate the search results. How do I do this? I presume it needs to do something like `?query=test&page=2`

Comment: @Cameron - probably best to start a new question about your new problem (helps with a more specific title, question text etc, not everyone will see these last comments, so they may not know you've got a follow up question).  Also if it's homework make sure you chuck the 'homework' tag on the question.  No issues helping with homework but it's good to know upfront.