# paging, sorting , filtering in asp.net mvc3 razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to do paging, sorting, filtering for a table in asp.net mvc3 razor without using webgrid. I had seen paged list..

[from this link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

here the paging appears like this << < Prev Next> >>  But i would like to display the paging format same as like in webgrid like < 1 2 3 4 5 > is it possible.. If not can any one please suggest me another method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Skip` and `Take` from Linq to implement paging: [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659978/asp-net-mvc-pagination-using-take-and-skip)

And you can use `Where` to filter and `OrderBy` to order